# dplyr, use filter with non-standard evaluation

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I would like to use the *filter()* function from **dplyr** with a dynamic variable name :

```
data(mtcars)
var1 <- 'hp'

mtcars %>% filter(hp == 110)      # works
mtcars %>% filter(var1 == 110)    # doesn't works
```

With new version of dplyr package, it seems to be possible to do this (without using the lazyeval package), but I don't manage to do it .. Some helps will be appreciated.

Tests without success :

```
mtcars %>% filter(!!var1 == 110)
mtcars %>% filter(!!!var1 == 110)
mtcars %>% filter((!!var1) == 110)
mtcars %>% filter(quo(var1) == 110)
mtcars %>% filter(~var1 == 110)
mtcars %>% filter(quo(~var1) == 110)
var2 <- enquo(var1)
```

Successfull tests with *select()* and *mutate()*:

```
mtcars %>% select(!!!var1) %>% head()      # works
```

Comment: Have you considered using [seplyr](https://www.r-bloggers.com/an-introduction-to-seplyr/) instead?

Comment: first time I heard about "seplyr". I will look at it, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one awkward looking solution using only the dplyr package and the fact that you can use SE alternatives (ending with _) with a character input. (See vignette("nse").)

```
library(dplyr) 
data(mtcars)
var1 <- "hp"
mtcars %>% filter_(paste(var1, "== 110"))
```

Comment: Should this be paste0()?

Comment: There is no reason to remove the space, so I picked `paste`, but `paste0` should give the exact same result. @Elin

Answer (score 4):

This works for me. There is a great list of posts on `tidyeval` [here](https://maraaverick.rbind.io/2017/08/tidyeval-resource-roundup/)

```r
library(dplyr)

data(mtcars)

# using quotation then unquote
var1 <- quo(hp)
mtcars %>% filter(!!var1 == 110)  
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1

mtcars %>% filter(UQ(var1) == 110)
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1

# using sym then unquote
var2 <- rlang::sym('hp')
mtcars %>% filter(UQ(var2) == 110)
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1

# put the value 110 in variable
var2 <- rlang::sym('hp')
val <- '110'
mtcars %>% filter(UQ(var2) == UQ(val))
#>    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> 1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#> 2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#> 3 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
```

Created on 2018-02-28 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: P.S: I like these two blog posts: [Link 1](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/prog_dplyr_01/) & [Link 2](http://colinfay.me/tidyeval-1/). Very easy to understand.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. The first option with var1 <- quo(hp) is not the one I'm looking for because it is for a shiny application. If the user chose 'hp' as a variable, I will have it in a parameter, as a string. So I can't used quo(hp), because here hp is not a string.

Answer (score -1):

the likely issue is that you are using the wrong `filter`.
try your code using `dplyr::filter()` instead