# Inverse of quo() in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, quosure

Using the new quosure syntax for dplyr 0.7.4, I believe I should be able to do something like `!!quo(1)` (expecting `1`), yet it returns the error

```
library(dplyr)
!!quo(1)
Error in !quo(1) : invalid argument type
```

Why doesn't this work? (Note that in base R, one can do `eval(quote(1))`. What is the dplyr analogue?)

... is `!!` only defined within dplyr functions?

Comment: See also my answer for some good refs https://stackoverflow.com/a/49035038/786542

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!!` is only defined within functions that are aware of the [tidyeval framework](http://rlang.tidyverse.org/), yes. In normal R code, it means two successive `!`'s (logical-not).

The equivalent of `eval` would be `rlang::eval_tidy`:

```
eval_tidy(quo(42))
# [1] 42
```

Comment: you mean `eval_tidy`?

Comment: `eval_tidy`, yes